# Regenerating js files from typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

I deleted a js file from Web express 2013 because the case was wrong :

go.js which was supposedly generated from go.js

How can I tell studio to regenerate the js file?

in the project I have:

```
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="ts\go.ts" />
```

but I still have the yellow triangle over the js file in solution explorer

Comment: Are you set to compile on build? Just re-building should result in a new JS file on the file system.

Comment: @SteveFenton please see my edit, both the .js and .map.js don't exist

Comment: @SteveFenton it complains that the don't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a build error will mean no TypeScript output, so clearing build errors may allow the compiler to run and make the files.

If that doesn't work, pop your code somewhere safe so you can delete the file and re-add it from scratch (then copy your code back in).